# What parts do I need for a strong robotic arm?

Tags: robotic-arm

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPhhYlIq294

I have found this robotic arm on the internet, and I was wondering if someone can tell me what parts I need to build it or similar. The video says it can lift a small cat.

I need to be able to program it, so I'll need a controller.

Please recommend specific motor, controller links that you recommend. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Zxen, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Okay, sorry. Should I remove it?

Comment: you could make it a bit more fitting by doing some research yourself first. Then you could mention what parts you have found, and what factors make it hard for you to decide which one to choose. That way, an answerer can specify exactly and scientifically the effect of the different parameters of the parts you have found, so you could have an idea how to compare them yourself, as well as understand which parameters are more important towards your goal. The question as is, is way too generic.

Answer (score 1):

The video link is to a universal robots robot (R10), it is a very high quality arm. I would rate it as one of the best in the world in it's class.

I recommend ROS industrial to drive the robotic arm:
http://rosindustrial.org/

If you are doing the mechanics yourself, and you want to get it to this quality, you will need some serious skill, a small team of engineers, and a lot of cash.

If you are just doing it by yourself as a hobby, you will probably want to start small:
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/ufactory/uarm-put-a-miniature-industrial-robot-arm-on-your

You can get it running with just a laptop and an Arduino. The project will be pretty cheap.

I get most of my serious gear from China (big motors, sensors + electronics), and design/create most of the mechanics myself. It takes a lot of effort and cash.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're really asking is what kind of actuator can I get that's powerful,  *inexpensive, and simple*, which rules out hydraulics.

I'm also building a robot arm... first to catch balls and hopefully [fencing!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuSCErmoYpY)
So I'm interested in speed and power, but not precision which is what most robots aim for.

To the best of my knowledge, if you want high power and use commodity parts, the answer is RC car motors and planetary gearboxes.

1. Motor: you need to get a sensored motor for precise running (especially during startup), braking, and counting revolutions. Here's an excellent recommendation:

[Revolver stubby](http://holmeshobbies.com/Revolver-S-Stubby-Sensored-Outrunner.html)
    Very high amount of torque in a compact size due to being an outrunner (likely the only sensored outrunner out there thanks to John Holmes)

1. Planetary gearbox:
   Look at BaneBots' P60 and P80 gearboxes.

I have used both of these to soup up a Scorbot 3 that I bought at a surplus depot and am impressed.

Comment: i found a robotic arm consists of motors, each motor consists of torque sensor, planetary gearbox, motor,encoder.
i saerch parts in http://aliexpress.com and also for part names in sites like: http://www.robotshop.com/en/mounts-hubs.html?p=2